# iOS Push Notification concept

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am fairly new to iOS development and wanted to know if my concept of how to set up and use push notifications on iOS.

So my general idea is that on each time the iOS app is opened (following Apple's guidelines) to register for push notifications and then handle the did register and failed to register methods. In the did register for push notifications I would post to my webserver the device id which I would store in the database with a last connected date.

The logic on the webserver side would be to update the existing record if the device id already exists to update the last connected date (there will be a cron job that purges device ids where they haven't been connected in the last 3 months say).

So once I have the device ids that are fairly current then I can iterate through these device ids when sending the push notifications, this way I won't be sending unnecessary pushes to devices that may not have the app installed any more.

Does this concept sound correct?

Answer (score 1):

This should let you understand.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this diagram only goes so far, I can see that it registers with apples apn as well as the notifier but doesn't show how to handle old devices etc